# Formulario registro con ajax y conexión PDO

Tags: mysql, ajax, base-de-datos, pdo, registro

Tengo el siguiente código de conexión a la db:

```
<?php
try
{
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=".localhost."; dbname=".php_registro, root, "");
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO:: ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch (PDOException $exception)
{
    die('Error: '.$exception);
}
?>
```

Al ejecutar el formulario me muestra el siguiente aviso:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected token "->" in C:\xampp\htdocs\route\Sistema-de-registro-y-login-basado-en-ajax-jquery-lightbox\ajax-login-registration.php on line 55
Donde en dicha línea tengo este código:

```
$selectQuery = $conn = new PDO->prepare(
    "select * from tbl_registro where email_id = ? and password = ?"
);
```

Qué debo corregir?
Muchas gracias y saludos cordiales.
Antonio Manuel

Comment: A tu conexión le llamas `$db`. La generas en la primera línea del `try`. Bien, pues después debería ser algo así como `$selectQuery = $db->prepare("select * from tbl_registro where email_id = ? and password = ?");` A partir de ahí, ya enlazar parámetros, etc. Y lo de `$conn`, o le llamas así a la conexión en todas partes (en lugar de `$db`), o lo obvias

Comment: Gracias por tu pronta respuesta, me sigue dando esta respuesta:Parse error: syntax error, unexpected variable "$db" in C:\xampp\htdocs\route\Sistema-de-registro-y-login-basado-en-ajax-jquery-lightbox\ajax-login-registration.php on line 55

Comment: La conexión original era: <!--?php
     $conn =new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '' , 'php_registro');
?--!


<?php y la línea 55 era: $selectQuery = $conn->prepare("select * from tbl_registro where email_id = ? and password = ?"); Así funcionaba sin error, luego quise modificar con PDO y este es el resultado. Gracias.

Comment: Pués ahora me dice lo siguiente al querer registrar un usuario:<!--?php $conn =new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '' , 'php_registro'); ?--! <br /> <b>Fatal error</b>: Uncaught Error: Undefined constant &quot;localhost&quot; in C:\xampp\htdocs\route\Sistema-de-registro-y-login-basado-en-ajax-jquery-lightbox\db.php:9 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\route\Sistema-de-registro-y-login-basado-en-ajax-jquery-lightbox\ajax-login-registration.php(5): require_once() #1 {main} thrown in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\route\Sistema-de-registro-y-login-basado-en-ajax-jquery-lightbox\db.php</b> on line <b>9</b><br />